# Visual Studio 2013 - Web Site installer project

Tags: wcf, iis, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2013, installation

I have two visual studio 2013 solutions:
1) Contains MVC application projects
2) Contains a  mix of WCF and WebApi service projects.

I would like to create two installer projects one for each solution that will self extract and install the websites into IIS 7.

Also I would like these installer project to be built by our TFS build server so the output from the nightly build is two MSI files. Double clicking either of these project will setup the website and backend web service with minimal effort on the person doing install.

Anyone done this? How did you do it?

Comment: Have you consider distributing a Web Application Package instead?

Answer (score 0):

Normal setup projects install ONE web application to one web site. I do not know of a third party setup project that will do this out of the box.

If you are up for the challenge, I would recommend checking out the WiX Toolset. 
You should be able to "script" everything in a WiX setup project and it will build your MSI files on your TFS build servers.

First find out how to create a WiX setup for 1 web application, then duplicate that code for each of your projects.

I recommend this tutorial. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/115036/Creating-WIX-Installer-for-ASP-NET-Web-Application

Based on this I created a simple web project installer.

Answer (score 0):

For MVC site, you should publish a web deploy package and import from IIS. [This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465323%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is very useful.

For other types of projects, you should use WiX projects to single click installations.

If you host the WCF services on the IIS, you should create second web package.

If you on a windows service, you can use the WiX Toolset Visual Studio extension. You just create a simple script and build it. It will create msi files.